# How to upload empty file with Retrofit 2?

Tags: rest, file-upload, retrofit

I successfully set up an uploading images to my REST API via retrofit with this code:

```
        File imageFile = ImagePicker.getFileFromResult(this, resultCode, data);
        RequestBody requestFile =
                RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), imageFile);
        MultipartBody.Part body =
                MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("userpic", imageFile.getName(), requestFile);

        RetrofitClient.compositeSubscription.add(RetrofitClient.getService().updateProfileUserpic("Token " + RevolutionApp.getInstance().getUserToken(), body).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Observer<Profile>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() { }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) { }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(Profile profile) {
                        mProfileFragment.fetchProfileData();
                    }
                }));
```

Now I need to send empty file (null) to my my API. How to implement it?

```
MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("userpic", imageFile.getName(), requestFile)
```

does not work

Comment: how your solved this issue,please tell me

Comment: Answer is here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is final solution:

API interface method to update model:

```
public void updateProfileData(ProfilePost profile, final OnProfileUpdatedListener listener) {

    Observable<Profile> observable;
    if (profile.getUserpicPart() != null) {
        observable = RetrofitClient.getService().updateProfileData(profile.asHashMap(), profile.getUserpicPart());
    } else {
        observable = RetrofitClient.getService().updateProfileData(profile.asHashMap());
    }

    RetrofitClient.compositeSubscription.add(observable
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Observer<Profile>() {
                ...
            }));
}
```

Retrofit method signature:

```
@PUT("/api/v1/profile/")
@Multipart
Observable<Profile> updateProfileData(@Header("Authorization") String authorization, @PartMap() Map<String, RequestBody> partMap, @Part MultipartBody.Part image);

@PUT("/api/v1/profile/")
@Multipart
Observable<Profile> updateProfileData(@Header("Authorization") String authorization, @PartMap() Map<String, RequestBody> partMap);
```

and model to post:

```
public class ProfilePost {
    MultipartBody.Part userpicPart;

    public HashMap<String, RequestBody> asHashMap() {
        HashMap<String, RequestBody> result = new HashMap<>();
        result.put("first_name", RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), this.firstName));
        result.put("last_name", RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), this.lastName));
        result.put("email", RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), this.email));
    }
    public void getUserpicPart() {
        if (this.userpicFile == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("userpic", this.userpicFile.getName(), requestFile);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your support, i solved in different way,check my answer

Comment: @Vassiliy How will you send null value while sending multiple images. My point is, if suppose i want to send 10 images and one of the image i want to send as null. then how can i achieve this with your solution. I dont think this solution will work.

Answer (score 6):

i don't Know this is the right way to do this,i tried like this.its working

```
MultipartBody.Part fileToUpload = null;
        if (realPath != null) {
            try {
                File file = new File(realPath);
                if (file.exists()) {
                    RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("*/*"), file);
                    fileToUpload = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("attachment", file.getName(), requestBody);
                }
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }else{
            RequestBody attachmentEmpty = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), "");

            fileToUpload = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("attachment", "", attachmentEmpty);
        }
```

Note: File Name should not be null ,in place of null use empty("").